# HSSFWorkbook time style setting when writing excel

Tags: java, hssfworkbook

I am creating time format style for Writing data in HSSFWorkbook but output is coming with different format and with once character appended to it.

```
HSSFCellStyle timeStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
timeStyle.setDataFormat(creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("HH:mm"));


String startTime =  "11:30" ;

cell.setCellStyle(timeStyle);
cell.setCellValue(startTime);
```

But the output of the excel is like

[image]

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me

Comment: sorry for not understanding. The excel output in your screen shot seems to be exactly what you want? Please elaborate what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not giving proper detail.. actually in function bar you can see actual value is '11:30 which was making problem.
But i found the issue as i was setting String "11:30" in cell with excel cell format as "HH:mm" instead of date "11:30" in cell.

String startTime =  "11:30" ;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

Date startDate = sdf.parse(startTime);

cell.setCellStyle(timeStyle);
cell.setCellValue(startDate);

It solved my problem with format issue.